# How to find this ^ in a specific position of a pattern

Tags: mysql, querying

Hello how would i query Mysql to find ^ in say position 18 of a pattern of unknown length  any help will be greatly appreciated

pattern

NN^^^NNN5^YN  may be longer

i have tried LIKE % %  REGEX ''  everything that is within my knowledge

Really curios how to do this

thanks in advance

Comment: Show the pattern you're using.

Comment: still waiting for the reason this was down-voted so i can know better in the future ?

Comment: @dayuloli thanks for the attempt but not what i asked and i dont find the humor in it

Comment: So you want to find all the locations, in the given example its on 3,4,5 and 10th posision ?

Comment: if ^ is in position 18 something is enabled i only need to query for the rows containing ^ in position 18

Comment: I dont think you need regex for this you can use substr() function to see the string with a specified location. If you want I can give some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find `^` in position 18 you can use Mysql's `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions

```
select left(details,18),
right(left(details,18),1) pattern 
from t having pattern ='^'
```

or

```
select *
from t 
where  right(left(details,18),1) ='^';
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83c1db/5)

Comment: Yes its the correct way, substr will again need to find the first char from the initially returned string.

Comment: thanks you it worked still curios why my question was down-voted